# put HTML element in prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I would like to create an object that extends the function of an HTML element by putting the element in the object's prototype chain.

I though I could do this with something like the following:

```
var el = document.createElement( "div" );
el.innerHTML = "foo";

var wrapper = Object.create( el );
alert( wrapper.innerHTML );
```

The above does not work, whereas the following does:

```
var el = document.createElement( "div" );
el.innerHTML = "foo";

var wrapper = Object.create( el );
alert( wrapper.__proto__.innerHTML );
```

It seems odd that explicitly looking inside the prototype would be necessary to find a given property.

Comment: Please don't mess with host objects, see [*Maintainable JavaScript: Don’t modify objects you don’t own*](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/). Also, hosts are not required to implement prototype inheritance for host objects, so you can't expect that they all will (IE didn't for a long time).

Comment: What is the **intent** behind creating a wrapper on top of `Element` or `HTMLDivElement`? What are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: The idea of a wrapper is OK, but putting the element on the wrapper's prototype chain is probably not the best way to do it. Just make it a property of the wrapper.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for your comment. I had never come across the term 'host object', or the idea that 'hosts are not required to implement prototype inheritance for host objects'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because you are using the `.innerHTML` getter on an object that is not a native DOM element and does have none of its internal slots.

> I would like to create an object that extends the function of an HTML element by putting the element in the object's prototype chain.

That's the wrong way round. To extend the functionality of an element, you need to put your custom function in its prototype chain, so that methods are still called on the element itself. You can use `Object.setPrototypeOf` for that, or make your own ES6 sub`class` (and possibly [register it as a custom element type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define)).

But the best solution would be to simply put a wrapper object around the element. Also have a look at http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/.

Comment: I thought that the prototype chain was automatically searched, though. So in my example code, since innerHTML isn't a property of wrapper, why isn't wrapper's prototype object automatically searched (as normally happens with plain JS objects)?

Comment: The prototype chain *is* searched and the `.innerHTML` getter is found just fine. But then the getter function complains that `wrapper` is not a DOM element (as `el` would have been) and it does not know how to get a html string from it. Notice that it does throw an `Illegal invocation` exception instead of just alerting `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi *But then the getter function complains that wrapper is not a DOM element*, but `wrapper instanceof HTMLElement` returns **true**.

Comment: @gurvinder372 It doesn't matter that `HTMLElement.prototype` can be found in the prototype chain (which is what `instanceof` checks). As I explained in the answer, `wrapper` does not have the custom internal slots that make it a dom element.

Comment: @Bergi Can you point me towards the spec/doc (or add to your answer only) that talks about internal slots being mandatory for an object to be a DOM element?

Comment: @gurvinder372 No, I can't. This behaviour does not seem to be detailed in any spec (not for [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), which is annoyingly missing from the standards, but also for other DOM properties). But it's just how host objects in EcmaScript usually work.

Comment: Thanks, the comments have helped me understand the situation a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create` creates a new object with the specified prototype object and **properties**. **`el` doesn't have any of its own enumerable properties**, you can check

```
Object.keys( el ) ; //[]
```

or

```
for( var key in el )
{
   if ( el.hasOwnProperty( key ) )
   {
      console.log( key )
   }
}
```

Thus you need to pass the properties with their descriptors, make it

```
var wrapper = Object.create( el, { "innerHTML" : { value: el.innerHTML } } );
```

**Demo**

```js
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.innerHTML = "foo";
var wrapper = Object.create(el, {
  "innerHTML": {
    value: el.innerHTML
  }
});
console.log(wrapper.innerHTML);
```

You can make it dynamic by **defining a `getter`** for `innerHTML`

```js
var el = document.createElement("div");
el.innerHTML = "foo";
var wrapper = Object.create(el, {
  "innerHTML": {
    get: function() { return el.innerHTML }
  }
});
console.log( wrapper.innerHTML );
el.innerHTML = "foo2";
console.log( wrapper.innerHTML );
```

Comment: @RobG yeah, noticed the same and defined a getter instead of plain value. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: My understanding is that if a given property is not owned by an object, its prototype chain will be searched. I don't understand why that doesn't happen here.

Comment: @DavidNewberry—because *innerHTML* is most likely implemented as a getter, and when "called" by *wrapper.innerHTML*, then *this* within the getter is the wrapper, not the object that the property is found on. All methods on prototypes work that way, e.g. `someObj.toString()` works on *someObj*, not *Object.prototype* (where the *toString* method would be found). It's the call that sets the value of *this*, it isn't lexical.